# Laravel Livewire Life hook livewire, v.2.11 updated/updating

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-9

When it try trigger to updated life hook when property is changed/updated not work
example

```
 ...
public function updatedName($name){
    dd($this->name);
}
```

and I find this message from livewire doc.

> Please note that mutating a property directly inside a Livewire component class doesn't trigger any of the updating/updated hooks.

Please. do someone can explain in detail this message from https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks meaning and what should be done instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning means that the Lifecycle Hooks are not called when you update a property inside the PHP component class.

An example usage is to catch when a user updates a property via the `wire:model` attribute.

```php
class HelloWorld extends Component
{
    public $foo;

    public function updatedFoo($value)
    {
        //
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->foo = "New Value";
        // updatedFoo will NOT be called
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" wire:model="foo" />
<!-- Entering text into this field will cause the hook to be called -->
```

Comment: Thank you. I get it.. so what if I want to change via function exampale `<button wire:click="changeName('newName')">change</button>`

Comment: you could probably just call `$this->updatedFoo($this->foo)` in your class, or extract the logic for `changeName` and `updatedFoo` to a new method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public $name;

public function updatedName($value)
    {
       // if you want get value
       dd($value);
     
      // if you want change name to new value 
       $this->name = $value
    }
```